# When updating the artifactory oss (docker) version we see an unexpected and undocumented version 7.21.3 (i.s.o. 7.19.10)

Tags: artifactory

When updating the  artifactory oss (docker) version we see an unexpected and undocumented version 7.21.3 (i.s.o. 7.19.10)

Please provide the release notes for the 7.21.x version(s).
Please explain why this is not working as expected.( update to version 7.19.10 ) and what are the differences ( if any, or not explained by release notes).

We were running version 7.19.9 before.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a programming question

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is not about a practical programming problem as outlined in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 7.23.1 is fully advertised on the [Release Notes](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Release+Notes#ArtifactoryReleaseNotes-Artifactory7.21.3) page.
For the reasons of releasing 7.19.10 (minor-minor), please read the [Release Notes](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Release+Notes#ArtifactoryReleaseNotes-Artifactory7.19.10) for this version.
The latest OSS version is available at https://jfrog.com/open-source/.
if you would like to pull a different version, please use appropriative tag (instead of latest):

```
docker pull releases-docker.jfrog.io/jfrog/artifactory-oss:7.19.10
```

Comment: The docker image was available before the release notes, this  created the confusion.